# Can someone know my browser and headset model via browsing a link?

Tags: privacy, url

I recently clicked on a malicious link on Reddit When I was directed to the link, it asked me to do a couple of captchas. I did them and then was redirected back to Reddit. Then he said he could see my handset brand and that I was changing browsers to open that link. So I want to know what other info he got from me.

I used a VPN called ThunderVPN. But it's not paid version so i was worried what sensitive info was leaked. Does he know my ID on social media like Facebook? Are my social media accounts compromised?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing here to suggest a compromise of anything. If he operated the servers you connected to, then he would know the browser you used and the audio hardware you used (because the browser announces itself and the available hardware). The captchas are likely to get more audio information (because of the audio option for most captchas)

So, there is nothing in what you have explained that suggests he knows anything more than what you broadcast to any site. There is no reason to assume anything more than that from what you have said.

The links could have exploited a vulnerability in your browser, and therefore know everything about you, but we can't assess that. If you are running a fully-updated browser, the chance is very low. And since all he talked about was what was already public, we can assume that he doesn't have any further info.

Comment: Thank you. I used UC Browser and I disconnected from the internet and cleared the cache as soon as I realised I was phished. Now I have changed the passwords just to be sure.